What Is the Best Symbolic Representation for a Time-Dependent Complex Expression?
I am working with the following term:
$$\hat{U}\cdot\frac{1}{2\cdot j}\cdot \Bigl[ \exp{(j\cdot\{\omega \cdot t + \phi\})} - \exp{(-j\cdot\{\omega \cdot t + \phi\})}  \Bigr]$$
where:

$j=\sqrt{-1}$ is the imaginary unit,
$t\in\mathbb{R}$ is the independent variable,
$\hat{U}, \phi, \omega \in\mathbb{R}$, are parameters.

This term simplifies to a purely real term:
$$ \hat{U}\cdot \sin{(\omega t + \phi)} $$
However, I do not wish to simplify the term. Instead, I would like to keep it in its original complex form.
My Question:
How can I define a notation to represent this term as part of an equation?
Here is my current idea:
I propose to write the expression as $\underline{U}(t)$, where:

the underline in $\underline{U}(t)$ indicates it is a complex number, and
$(t)$ in $\underline{U}(t)$ indicates the expression is time-dependent.

So the complete equation would look like this:
$$\underline{U}(t)=\hat{U}\cdot\frac{1}{2\cdot j}\cdot \Bigl[ \exp{(j\cdot\{\omega \cdot t + \phi\})} - \exp{(-j\cdot\{\omega \cdot t + \phi\})}  \Bigr]$$
What I Need Help With:
Does this notation make sense? Would a typical math or physics student understand this definition of $\underline{U}(t)$? Is there a more standard way to define such a time-dependent complex term?

Sure. You're defining a function $\underline U:\Bbb R\to\Bbb C.$

thanks karl! or is it better to use the symbol $\underline{u}(t)$, since $u$ in physics small letters are generally used for time dependent functions. I am not sure :(

Either way is fine! There are no universal conventions for function naming - just choose notation that makes sense. (The underline is a little unusual and arguably unnecessary, but it's not "wrong". Maybe it's useful if you have many functions and want to clearly distinguish the complex-valued ones.)
